# Checking all Data Value in Table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="input-group select-all" >
    <span class="input-group-addon disabled">
        <input type="checkbox" <?php if($pagetitle=="Trash") echo "disabled"?>>
            </span>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle <?php if($pagetitle=="Trash") echo "disabled"?>" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
```

When we checked in checkbox then all the data in a table must be selected, which is the type of operation I need.

```
<div class="mails">
            <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                <?php
                if(count($inMessages)>0)
                    foreach($inMessages as $m):
                        ?>
                        <tr data-id="<?php echo $m->sn?>" <?php if($m->flag==1) echo "class=\"read\""?><?php if($m->flag==0) echo "class=\"unread\""?>>
                            <td><?php if($pagetitle!="Trash"):?><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-square-o disabled" data-id="<?php echo $m->sn?>"></i><?php endif?></td>
                            <td class="subject"><?php echo $m->subject?></td>
                            <td class="body"><?php echo $m->message?></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $m->address?>
                                <BR/><?php echo $m->io?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="time"><?php echo $m->mdate?> <?php echo $m->mtime?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    endforeach
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /Right Side mail bar -->
```

Manual check box works properly, but I need check all options.

How can I do that in addition to the code above? Please help me.

Comment: Hi Sabin, basically each table row appears to have a data id. Am I right to assume you want the contents of each table data item and not the html? Is that what you mean by "all the data in the table"?  Also, how are you submitting this data back to the server?  It looks like javascript can easily do the job, and jQuery makes the start of this much simpler. Are you expecting someone to write the whole script for you, or have you already started this?  a codepen or jsfiddle or similar would help people help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all with a single checkbox you can use something similar to:

```
<?php
$string .= '
<table id="mytable" class="table table-hover table-bordered datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"></th>
      <th>Field A</th>
      <th>Field B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>'."\n";
foreach($array as $row) { // create table content
  $string .= '    <tr id="art-'.$row['field'].'" class="data">
      <td><input class="case" type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'.$row['field'].'"></td>
      <td>'.$row['field A'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['field B'].'</td>
    </tr>'."\n";
}
  $string .= '    </tbody>
</table>
'."\n";
echo $string;
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selectall").click(function () {  // check all
    $('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

  // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
  // and viceversa
  $(".case").click(function(){
    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
      $("#selectall").prop("checked", "checked");
    } else {
      $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```